# AD RMS using with Sharepoint 2010 and Form Based Authtication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, forms-authentication, information-management

I am working on a project, the need is that the site is for extranet and by using form based authtication the users can access the portal, I am stack at a point where I have to implement the RMS services for externet user, means using form based authtication the user should have limited rights on office document. Anyone has an idea about this, RMS can work with Sharepoint form based authtication? or it just work with windows authtication?

Comment: There's an older thread on the MS forums which seems to suggest that IRM/RMS and FBA aren't really the intended use case. Your clients would need to set a registry key to point to your RMS server and you would need to set up FBA to use an AD membership provider.  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointadmin/thread/9f6612b2-ad02-47b8-835f-02ba3d93ca9a

Comment: Thanks to reply, the link is quite older, after that there are not any further solutions and changes on Microsoft side? or we might have any alternative solution for that?

Comment: Well, the issue is RMS is integrated with AD DS. You can also use Windows Live IDs, but if you are using a custom FBA provider that uses neither AD DS or WLID I don't believe there is going to be a way for RMS to authenticate user and authorize the RMS license.

Answer (score 0):

"RMS can work with Sharepoint form based authtication?" Yes, RMS can work with SP FBA.  Please have a look at my comment in this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/d652f16a-a5a9-4263-8c1c-61bf13265afe/ad-rms-with-sharepoint-form-based-authentication